# inconsistent results from shell script mv

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm having an issue with a simple shell script that merely moves a file from one location to another.  It takes the source & target paths & names as parameters.  Code is as follows...

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
  exit 1
else
  ls -l $1
  mv -v $1 $2
  X=$?
  echo 'Move completion code = ' $X
  ls -l $2
  exit $X
fi
```

This script is called multiple times in a sequential job schedule, loading data to (replacing) the same file.  Recently seeing instances where the job after the move script runs with data from the file that existed before - indicating that it was not overwritten - yet the messages in the move script show a successful move - and checking the file itself shows it with the expected data.  Any ideas?  Could the script be completing before the mv command has fully completed?  I've put the completion code message in to check for this, I've also tried sleeping for 5 sec.  What am I missing?
Thanks!

Update...
Here's the output after adding the md5sum checks....

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 appworx dba 22 Aug 10 12:15 UP.dat
Before move - file 1
9bf394b473cf389d704357e4da46fcfa UP.dat
`UP.dat' -> `ids.dat'
removed `UP.dat'
After move - file 2
9bf394b473cf389d704357e4da46fcfa  
Move completion code =  0 
-rw-r--r--. 1 appworx dba 22 Aug 10 12:15 load_ids.dat
```

Comment: `mv` is not asynchronous. When it finishes, the move has completed. Are you sure the file isn't being recreated by some other process?

Comment: Put `md5sum $1` and `md5sum $2` in the script to confirm that the destination file has been updated.

Comment: and post the output

Comment: Does the file names within $2 contain any white-spaces? You should quote the variables.

Comment: Are you sure there is a ; after the if statement ?

Comment: added the md5sum commands - posting output in the original question.  This script seems to be working fine to me.  But still, the data that's being processed by the subsequent script comes from earlier files.  Thinking the problem could be with the pl/sql.

Comment: Your problem _could_ be related to the fact that — If a process already has a file open it will continue to use that file even if that file is moved/renamed.  A process will still see a file that it has open even if that file is unlinked (I don't mean symbolic links, "removed" is actually unlinked)

Comment: I suggest adding the `-i` option to the `ls` commands, and also listing both `"$1"` and `"$2"` in both `ls` commands.  This will tell you about the inode numbers (that's the `-i`) and whether the files exist before and after the move (you'd expect the second `ls` to fail with 'no such file or directory' for `$1`, for example).